# Add plus 1 hour of slotLabelFormat in Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) and have this table

[image: fullcalendar example]

On the left side there are hours

```
        function GenerateCalender(events) {
        $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#calender').fullCalendar({
            height: 'auto',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            minTime: "10:00:00",
            maxTime: "24:00:00",
            columnFormat: 'DD' + ' - ' + 'dddd',
            slotDuration: "00:60:01",
            //slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',
            viewSubSlotLabel: true,
            eventOverlap: false,
            slotLabelFormat: [
                'HH:00'
            ],
            eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
                $(element).css('width', '123px');
            },
            allDaySlot: false,
            contentHeight: 741,
            //height: 741,
            timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today'
            },
         }
```

In slotLabelFormat I want to show two hours, starting and ending, so the hours will be shown as

```
10:00 - 11:00
11:00 - 12:00
12:00 - 13:00
13:00 - 14:00 etc...
```

But I was not able to achieve this from fullcalendar documentation and such.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can, just by using the slotLabelFormat. But then again, why do you need to? It's obvious when the timeslot finishes - it finishes when the next one starts. IMO it's better not to overload the UI with redundant information like that, it just clutters things up. I imagine that might be one reason why the developers of fullCalendar didn't choose to support this extra functionality.

Comment: @ADyson I agree but that is what is demanded...

Comment: Well our job as programmers is not only to fulfil the customer's every desire and whim, no matter if it's impossible and/or pointless. So now you have to challenge the requirements. You have good grounds for it: 1) it doesn't add to the user experience, for the reasons I mentioned. 2) Even if they disagree with point 1), fixing it will require a customisation of the fullCalendar source code which will be time-consuming and expensive (since you're not experienced with that code), and also make it hard to upgrade the calendar in future (again expensive).

Comment: If the cost doesn't put them off, then you just explain the downsides, get in writing an agreement that they understand they're storing up problems for the future and start off down the road of customising the view code etc. Or you spend lots of time/money re-writing the all your other functionality to work with some other calendar plugin which happens to provide this tiny, pointless feature. That's another option you can give them. Hopefully they will see sense at this point... :-)